# Regex: Avoid words which include letter after period

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am interested in selecting any form of `ES` letters as the first word in a string which might be replaced by any of its different forms (`E.S.` or `E-S` or `E - S`,`E&S` or `E & S` or `E S` or `E/S` or `E<punctuation>S`) instead of just `ES`. No other letter should appear in the same word.

Consider the full dateset of names:

```
E.S.P. BS.
E. & S. BS.
ES ENERGY
E.S.C. BS.
E.S. BS.
E.S.K. BS.
E.S.G. BS.
ES.K.JI BS.
```

Just the words including any form of `ES` should be considered. For instance, `E.S.` or `E-S` or `E - S`,`E&S` or `E & S` or `E S` should be included.

Here the analysis is just in the first word. The following should not be included because after ES form the first word includes more letters:

```
E.S.P. BS. #Extra P.
E.S.C. BS. #Extra C.
E.S.K. BS. #Extra K.
E.S.G. BS. #Extra G.
ES.K.JI BS. #Extra K.JI
```

On the other hand, these strings are obtained correctly:

```
E. & S. BS.
ES ENERGY
E.S. BS.
```

The regex I am using for this selection is the next:

```
^(e\W*s)\W*(?!\w)\b
```

I am not sure why this regex pattern is not working. How can I ensure just any form of `ES` is considered?

Thanks

Comment: The rules are not 100% clear but maybe start with `^E(?:\s*\W\s*)*S\b(?!\.[A-Z])`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/4S7CW4/1

Comment: `r"^E[\. &]*S\.? "` works for your example list of names. You can add more punctuation chars to the character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the last character of the first word is the first character equal to or following `'S'` that is followed by a space. If so, you could use `re.findall` to match the string with the following regular expression.

```
r'^[^A-Z]*E[^A-Z]*S[^A-Z ]*(?= )'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/eRd9Rx/1) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python code](http://tpcg.io/JNhgv0Q9)